# Add image left and right to link with CSS class

Tags: css, hyperlink

i need to add an small image to the left and right from a hyperlink. This will be reused several times with different images, so I need to do it in CSS with classes.
I succeeded already to either the left http://jsfiddle.net/XAh2d/9257/

```
.fuss {background: transparent url(https://elternwerkstatt.domaincontrol.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/fusspaar-rot_18px.png) center left no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;}
```

or to the right http://jsfiddle.net/k59zhwg3/1/

```
.fuss {background: transparent url(https://elternwerkstatt.domaincontrol.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/fusspaar-rot_18px.png) center right no-repeat; padding-right: 20px;}
```

but as soon i try to use two classes for left AND right, it didnt work, only one image shows up:  http://jsfiddle.net/7jcqxa3v/10/

```
.fuss-rechts {background: transparent url(https://elternwerkstatt.domaincontrol.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/fusspaar-rot_18px.png) right no-repeat; padding-right: 20px;}
.fuss-links {background: transparent url(https://elternwerkstatt.domaincontrol.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/fusspaar-rot_18px.png) left no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;}

 in HTML: <a class="fuss-links fuss-rechts" target="_blank" href="https://elternwerkstatt.domaincontrol.at">hier mein link</a>
```

Any help appreciated!  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your CSS class like this to achieve it:

```
    .fuss {
       background: transparent;
       background-image: url(https://elternwerkstatt.domaincontrol.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/fusspaar-rot_18px.png), url(https://elternwerkstatt.domaincontrol.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/fusspaar-rot_18px.png);
       background-position:left,right;
       background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
       padding-left:20px;
       padding-right:20px;
     }
```

Comment: you can use the  following too, to avoid  boilerplated  code:                                                       `.fuss {
  background: transparent url(https://elternwerkstatt.domaincontrol.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/fusspaar-rot_18px.png), url(https://elternwerkstatt.domaincontrol.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/fusspaar-rot_18px.png) no-repeat, no-repeat left, right;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected behavior. The CSS class `fuss-links` is overwriting the `background` rule set by `fuss-rechts` since it comes 2nd in the stylesheet, since CSS rulesets prioritize rules that come last (hence the C for cascading in CSS).

To my knowledge, you cannot achieve the desired effect using just the CSS `background` rule, since it does not allow you to repeat elements only on the edges, you can either never repeat or repeat across the entire width (source: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-repeat/).

My suggestion would be to move the images to `<img>` tags inside the `<a>` tag and to use `position: absolute;` to achieve the effect you want. You can see any example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/7jcqxa3v/22/

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the overwriting / cascading, I will remember that!
The solution with images inside links is working too, but this was the original scenario which we tried to avoid because of mass of links. Thank you!